# scraping data from webpage with python 3, need to log in first

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519698/log-in-to-webpage-with-python-to-scrape-data) but it only has one answer and it's a little over my head (just started with Python). I'm using Python 3.

I'm trying to scrape data from [this page](http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1820315%27), but if you have a BP account, the page is a lot different/more useful. I need my program to log me in before I have BeautifulSoup get the data for me.

So far I have

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request 
import requests

username = 'myUsername'
password = 'myPassword'

from requests import session

payload = {'action': 'Log in',
       'Username: ': username,
       'Password: ': password}

# the next 3 lines are pretty much copied from a different StackOverflow
# question. I don't really understand what they're doing, and obviously these 
# are where the problem is.

with session() as c:
    c.post('https://www.baseballprospectus.com/manageprofile.php', data=payload)
    response = c.get('http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1820315')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

for row in soup.find_all('tr')[7:]:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    name = cells[1].text
    print(name)
```

The script does work, it just pulls the data from the site before it's logged in, so its not the data I want.

Comment: Might I suggest you look into something like Fiddler or Burp Suite (HTTP proxies) to see the actual request being made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, there is no problem with your code. You're using a session object to send a login request, then with the same session you're sending a request for the desired page. This means that the cookies set by the login request should be kept for the second request. If you want to read more about the workings of the Session object, here's the relevant [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/).

Since I don't have a valid login for Baseball Prospectus, I'll have to guess that something is wrong with the data you're sending to the login page. A quick inspection using the 'Network' tab in Chrome's Developer Tools, shows that the login page, manageprofile.php, accepts four POST parameters:

```
username: myUsername
password: myPassword
action: muffinklezmer
nocache: some long number, e.g. 2417395155
```

However you're sending a different set of parameters, and specifying a different value for the 'action' parameter. Note that the parameter names have to match the original request exactly, otherwise manageprofile.php will not accept the login.

Try replacing the payload dictionary with this version:

```
payload = {
       'action': 'muffinklezmer',
       'username': username,
       'password': password}
```

If this doesn't work, try adding the 'nocache' parameter too, e.g.:

```
'nocache': '1437955145'
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried all this, and it didn't work. I then noticed that I had my payload 'username' and 'password' capitalized, so I switched those to lower case and now I'm getting an error in my iteration through the table that I'm pulling. (It's giving me a NameError, says a variable is not defined.) I then switch back to the uppercase username/password and it runs fine. This makes me think that maybe it is actually logging in with the correct case, and my list indices are off for the new table I'm pulling? I'm going to look into it.

Comment: I don't think the NameError has anything to do with the capitalization of the payload dictionary values. Whether the script succeeds or fails to log in, it will continue on to the for loop. To check if the script succeeded in logging in, I suggest that you temporarily comment out the for loop completely and just save `response.content` to a file, to see whether the output is what you expected to see in a logged in session.